# About the word 'aurora': which time preposition to use?

Tags: prepositions, poetic, seasons

*Aurora*, in poetic language, means dawn, according to some dictionaries.

How commonly is it used to indicate time?

I've mostly encountered *by dawn* and *in the morning* and was wondering if that's the case with *aurora* as well.

Which is the correct form? *At aurora, in aurora, by aurora, on aurora*?

Additionally, is it nice to use this prepositional phrase at the beginning of a sentence as to indicate the time at which an event happens?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

We don't use *aurora* to mean a particular time of day.  *Aurora* in English signifies "dawn" only indirectly, as the name of the Roman goddess who personified dawn. The English common noun [aurora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora) denotes a shimmering display of light in the sky.

Comment: Hmm, alright. Would you perhaps know where it is used under the dawn context? The dictionary gives its second meaning as 'literary: the dawn'.

Comment: @Veo That would be as a personification: _as Aurora made her entrance_, meaning _at dawn_.

Comment: @Veo It is ordinarily a name, a personification, spelled with a capital and referred to with the feminine personal pronoun. For instance: "So breaks Aurora through the veil of night, Thus fly the clouds, divided by her light." -Congreve

Answer (score 1):

I've always heard "at dawn", as in "pistols at dawn".  Thus, if "aurora" were indeed an *exact* synonym of "dawn", presumably this means you would say "at aurora".

However, I do not believe that the two are completely interchangeable.  "Dawn" can refer either to the time of day or the actual appearance of the sky.  I think that, by any broadly accepted usage, "aurora" could only refer to the appearance, not the time.

Comment: There are lot of translations of _The Odyssey_ that frequently use the phrase "now when rosy-fingered Dawn, the child of morning, appeared" to mean "at dawn".   If you want to go for hard-core, full-on poetry, I guess you could drop "Aurora" into that phrase.

Comment: @DougWarren *Dawn* there is Greek *Eos*, the equivalent of Latin *Aurora*; 17th-18th century translators routinely rendered it as *Aurora*.